# Languages/platforms that are meet listed requirements

Tags: compilation, language-agnostic, cross-platform, open-source

What programming languages (or platforms, or toolchains) are met these characteristic?

1. Have open source compiler and open source standard library
2. Compilable to the x86, x86_64 and ARMv7 architectures
3. Compilable to the Windows and Linux operating systems
4. Can be bundled in standalone executable (single file or directory of files), and not require some external library or interpreter to run (like JVM or Python or .NET). For example - if I download executable targeted for my platform (e.g. SomeSoftware_Win_x64.exe), I can just click and run this program, without any prerequisites or setup. It should not be some third party tool for bundling (like Launch4J for Java). This feature must come with language out of the box.

My list:

1. Rust
2. Go
3. .NET core

...

Comment: Xojo meets 2, 3, 4, but not 1. http://www.xojo.com

Comment: @PaulLefebvre Great! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few more obvious options include C, C++, D, Free Pascal, Racket, Common Lisp, Fortran, Haskell, Ada and Go.